# Chapter-2 example on countrychunks

Tags: itext

I am trying to run Countrychunks example from the Chapter 2.  The example works but the line: `document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);` does not produce the new line and the loop overwrites the first line. I am posting my code here in case I am doing anything wrong:

```
 public void createCountryChunks(String fileName)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Font font;
            Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

            //PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileName)).setInitialLeading(16);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE);

            foreach (var p in myProducts)
            {
                // add a country to the document as a Chunk
                document.Add(new Chunk(p.pr_name));
                document.Add(new Chunk(" "));
                Chunk id = new Chunk(p.pr_URN.ToString(), font);

                // with a background color
                id.SetBackground(BaseColor.BLACK, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, 1.5f);

                // and a text rise
                id.SetTextRise(6);
                document.Add(id);
                document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            }

            document.Close();
        }
```

As you can see the example is a bit different because of the data but the rest is almost the same as the original Java example.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: That was absolutely correct - I would have never thought this.  The reason I failed to bring over "setInitialLeading" to .Net library was that I simply couldn't find it. Now I found it's actually called InitalLeading, without "set".  Also because I can't get to the full iTextSharp library API.

Thank you for your reply - saved me lot of time.  Would you know any link for the API documentation at all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `setInitialLeading` call that you weren't able to bring over and was commented out was actually very important. Adding that back in will solve your problems. I really don't like to add properties directly onto my constructed objects so I'm going to do it in two lines:

```
var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
w.InitialLeading = 16;
```